# Call activity method from BroadcastReceiver Class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm a beginner to Android and Kotlin. Im developing an audio player with audio controls in notification. In my `Audio` activity I have public methods `playAudio()` and `pauseAudio()`. I need to call this method from a broadcast receiver as below

```
class AudioControlsInNotification : BroadcastReceiver() {
        var audioMain: Audio? = null
        fun setMainActivityHandler(main: Audio) {
            audioMain = main
        }
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent != null) {
              when (intent.action) {
                   "PAUSEAUDIO" -> {
                        audioMain?.pauseAudio()
                    }
                    "PLAYAUDIO" -> {
                        audioMain?.playAudio()
                    }
         }
    }
}
```

`audioMain` always returns null.
While clicking Play and Pause button,

```
notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "MYAUDIOCHANNEL")
contentView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.audio_notification)

val notifyPauseIntent = Intent(this, AudioControlsInNotification::class.java).apply {
  action = "PAUSEAUDIO"
}
val notifyPausePendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,notifyPauseIntent,0)
contentView!!.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifyPause, notifyPausePendingIntent)

val notifyPlayIntent = Intent(this, AudioControlsInNotification::class.java).apply {
action = "PLAYAUDIO"
}
val notifyPlayPendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,notifyPlayIntent,0)
contentView!!.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifyPlay, notifyPlayPendingIntent)
```

I received intent actions in the `AudioControlsInNotification` but i can't access the methods of `Audio` Activity. I tried many answers from stackoverflow but nothing helps me. I need this `BroadcastReceiver` on for this Audio activity only.

Answer (score 0):

> In my Audio activity I have public methods

That can only make sense if they are declared static in your activity class.

If they are not static then hat does not make sense as you have no pointer to your activity as activities cannot be created with the `new operater` but only using an intent.